# USRP E312 how to get gps information from internal gps receiver

Tags: usrp

How would you access gps information (say latitude, longitude) from the internal gps receiver with a gps antenna connected to a USRP E312? I'm using python2 generated by gnuradio for all of my code. I'm thinking maybe there's a command I can call from the uhd.

Comment: The antenna is an antenna. It doesn't give positional info. It just connects the electromagnetic waves that are then used by the integrated GPS receiver! Am I getting this correctly, you want to use the integrated GPS receiver of the E312?

Comment: Yes sorry, the wording is off. I know how an antenna works, I just messed up the question (agian). So yes, I connected a gps antenna to the gps port of the E312 but I don't know how to get information from the gps receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the E310 itself, the GPS module is handled by [`gpsd`](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/), which should be part of the image you're running. You should be able to interface with that using `libgps`. You could use the `gpspipe` tool to test:

```
gpspipe -w
```

Comment: gpspipe worked great. Didn't even know about that command until today. Isn't libgps a C library though? Which python gps library would work well for just time, lat, and lon collections?

Comment: yes, a C library. I recommend *reading the documentation* on the gpsd page; the libgps documentation page on there says something about Python.